# Vue3: why do we need useFunc() in composables?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Vue3 official docs say composables should expose state vars through useFunc()

```
#compose1.js
const varName = reactive({object})
export const useFunc = () => return {varName}
```

like useMouse() in https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html

But it looks like reactive or ref wrapped vars work well, even if exposed directly

```
#compose2.js
export const varName = reactive({object})
```

i.e. changes to those vars are synced across components

Is there any benefit of wrapping those reactive/refs in a useFunc()?

PS: basically I need a stateful composable, but not as complex as a pinia store

Comment: Probably just a better engineering practice, since you can refactor the `useFunc` to do anything different without changing its interface and touching the modules that import it, but you can't do that when exporting `varName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it is a recommendation to expose variables through composables. So you don't have to do it that way.

However, there are advantages to sticking to the formula:

- readability: whenever you see a function like `use*`, you know it is a composable, i.e. something that comes from outside and provides logic across components - with an imported variable, you don't.
- maintainability: very likely, you will want to attach logic to your data or add related data at some point - a watcher realizing a side-effect, a function to reset the data, a promise for components to watch during load, etc. - if you already use a function returning an object, you can easily enhance it.

If you are familiar with OOP, I think you can look at refs as primitives and composables as constructors (or builders) that create semantic entities which bundle (primitve) data and behavior. And with both, the idea is to avoid ending up with function and data floating around without context.

Not sure though how much of this is opinion. Hope it still helps

Comment: Seems to be an overkill. `use*` function still needs to be destructured and those var names will be the same as they are right now without the `use*` function

Comment: Oh, I know. Then again, pretty much every single time I tried to be clever and have a composable return the variable directly, I ended up having to change it later on. But if you don't mind that (which I didn't), no one is going to sue you for not returning an object from a composable or even exporting the data directly.